# Why does Activemq with ZooKeeper fail with NullPointerException upon stopping LevelDB service?

Tags: activemq-classic, leveldb

I have a ZooKeeper cluster with 3 instances and Apache ActiveMQ 5.9.1 cluster. The ZooKeeper cluster starts fine, but ActiveMQ gives the following NullPointerException:

```
 WARN | SASL configuration failed: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No
JAAS configuration section named 'Client' was found in specified JAAS configurat
ion file: 'D:\RepoHill30\apache-activemq\bin\..\conf\login.config'. Will continu
e connection to Zookeeper server without SASL authentication, if Zookeeper serve
r allows it.
 INFO | Opening socket connection to server 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:2888
 WARN | unprocessed event state: AuthFailed
ERROR | Failed to start Apache ActiveMQ ([localhost, null], java.util.concurrent
.TimeoutException: timeout reached while waiting on the lock: java.lang.Object@3
33d4a8c)
 INFO | Apache ActiveMQ 5.9.1 (localhost, null) is shutting down
 INFO | Connector openwire stopped
 INFO | Connector amqp stopped
 INFO | Connector stomp stopped
 INFO | Connector mqtt stopped
 INFO | Connector ws stopped
ERROR | Could not stop service: Replicated LevelDB[D:\RepoHill30\apache-activemq
\bin\..\data\LevelDB, localhost:2888,localhost:2889,localhost:2890//activemq/lev
eldb-stores]. Reason: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.activemq.leveldb.replicated.ElectingLevelDBStore.doStop(ElectingLevelDBStore.scala:276)
    at org.apache.activemq.util.ServiceSupport.stop(ServiceSupport.java:71)
    at org.apache.activemq.util.ServiceStopper.stop(ServiceStopper.java:41)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.stop(BrokerService.java:775)
    at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerService.stop(XBeanBrokerService.java:122)
    at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService.start(BrokerService.java:601)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.runTask(StartCommand.java:88)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:57)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.runTask(ShellCommand.java:150)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:57)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.main(ShellCommand.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.runTaskClass(Main.java:262)
    at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.main(Main.java:115)
```

**Part of ActiveMQ configfile:**

```
<persistenceAdapter>
    <replicatedLevelDB
      directory="${activemq.data}/LevelDB"
      replicas="3"
      bind="tcp://0.0.0.0:0"
      zkAddress="localhost:2888,localhost:2889,localhost:2890"
      zkPassword="password"
      zkPath="/activemq/leveldb-stores"
      hostname="localhost"
      />
</persistenceAdapter>
```

**Zookeeper configfile:**

```
tickTime=2000
dataDir=D:/zookeeper/zookeeper/cluster/server1/data
clientPort=2181
initLimit=5
syncLimit=2
server.1=localhost:2888:3888
server.2=localhost:2889:3889
server.3=localhost:2890:3890
```

Any help, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's due to this bug [ElectingLevelDBStore - NPE in doStop](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-5097) that's unfortunately still unresolved.

As a workaround, delete all data dirs and start over.